# Joomla 3.0 - Content creation

Tags: joomla

I used to work with drupal and I'm actually a complete noob concerning Joomla. I'd like to know how I can create custom content types like in Drupal. For example, I want one content type where a user can type some text and submit a picture and both text and picture are then published in the frontend.
How can I achieve this in Joomla?

Thanks and best regards,

enne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla natively supports many types of content, sometimes it's just a matter of setting the right options / enabling the right plugins.

If however what you need is not handled by Joomla, and there is no 3rd party extension out there which satisfies your requirements, there is a class of extensions called CCK (Content Creation Kits) which make custom content types available in Joomla:

- breezingforms and formtocontent let you design very nice forms and have limited support for backend (CRUD)
- Zoo, K2 and Sobi offer you endless possibilities but are large and heavy products
- ContentBuilder lets you inject code at any stage so it's usually the fastest and most versatile but does take more effort to setup.

and there are many more... checkout

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/directory
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

and lookup the ones I mentioned by name.

Answer (score 0):

"Content types" in Joomla! are handled by extensions, in this case "components". So you have a couple of options:

1. Write your own extension, see [developer docs on joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers), especially "[Developing a MVC Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_MVC_Component)".
2. Find a ready made extension on the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/).
3. Hire someone to write it for you.